# Build Issue: Execution failed for task ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'

Tags: ros, java, rosjava, gradle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to perform the java installation listed here:  http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

I ran into the following issue:

> :rosjava_messages:generateSources
> Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.ros.internal.message.GenerateInterfaces.main(GenerateInterfaces.java:162)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an
> exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'.
>
> > Command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'
> > finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

Here is line 162 (GenerateInterfaces.java:162):

```
160     String rosPackagePath = System.getenv(EnvironmentVariables.ROS_PACKAGE_PATH);
161     Collection<File> packagePath = Lists.newArrayList();
162     for (String path : rosPackagePath.split(File.pathSeparator)) {
163       File packageDirectory = new File(path);
164       if (packageDirectory.exists()) {
165         packagePath.add(packageDirectory);
166       }
167     }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59079/build-issue:-execution-failed-for-task-%27:rosjava_messages:generatesources%27./) by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on 2013-03-25**:
Part of the problem that I'm seeing here is that  'EnvironmentVariables.ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'  is null.  The environment variable is just not set at this point.  I don't know where it is supposed to be set, or why it is not set, but I will investigate.

**Comment by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on 2013-03-25**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue is currently waiting to be patched:

https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=135&sort=-id

In the meantime, you may be able to get around the problem by setting the environment variable ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as defined here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) with karma: 103 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0